# Linting, Formatting in an Nx Monorepo with Husky

Tags: prettier, typescript-eslint, husky, lint-staged, nx-monorepo

I have an nx monorepo with the following structure

```
apps/
libs/
 - angular/
 - react/
 - vue/
..

package.json
```

What is the best way to configure ESLint and Prettier for all sub-projects (angular, react and vue) ? and configure git hooks with Husky as well

Comment: I found this useful article https://www.thisdot.co/blog/linting-formatting-and-type-checking-commits-in-an-nx-monorepo-with-husky